# Error when manually creating a bibliography on a mac

Tags: biblatex, texmaker, mactex

I tried to use the following structure:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}


\begin{document}

... \cite{123}...


\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{123} A. B. C, Test.

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Using MikTex and Texmaker for windows, everything runs perfectly. But when using MacTex and Texmaker, I cannot run my tex files anymore.  When running LaTeX+Bib(la)tex (on a mac)+..  I always face the same error:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014) 
The top-level auxiliary file: FILE.aux 
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file FILE.aux 
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file FILE.aux 
(There were 2 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Using \usepackage{biblatex} instead of \usepackage{cite} definitely works for me. Anyone could explain why, please? Could, please, anyone answer me if someone using MikTex will face problems when compiling my FILE.tex? Is there any way to continue using cite package?

Comment: I have to complete that using \usepackage{biblatex} my references apear like [123] inside the text and not like [1] as desired. In this way I have to manage the correct number to any new entrance I use. can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Hi and welcome, if you want to do the job by hand, why do you call a program to do the job for you? That is contradictory.

Comment: By the way, you can edit your question to add any information.

Comment: I don't understand. You said you use biblatex, but you'r exemple explaind you use the cite package.

Comment: ops.. you are right:

Comment: Thank you, Johannes_B. So if I am using cite package is it not necessary to call Bib(la)tex?

Comment: Yeah.. thank you again... it works!!! I changed my sequence of commands to compile the file.. :)

Comment: If you're writing the bibliography manually, `biblatex` is completely irrelevant. With `cite` you can get some features such as sorting and compressing. Surely you don't need to call BibTeX (nor Biber).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three basic options how to include the bibliography:

1. Using biblatex. This consists of loading the package `\usepackage{biblatex}`, attaching the `.bib` file, and using one of the two external tools: `biber` or `bibtex`. You are not supposed to use `\begin{thebibliography}` at all! Just [read the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf) for the details.
2. Using BibTeX. You don't need to load any package, but you need to run an external tool, in this case it's `bibtex`. Again, no `\begin{thebibliography}` in your code!
3. Inputting the bibliography manually using `\begin{thebibligraphy}...`. In this case, you do not load `\usepackage{biblatex}` nor you run any external tools. As egreg points out, you can use some features of the package `cite`, but it's a bit strange.

To conclude, you have to choose either 1, 2 or 3, but not mix them together.